# Good reference + feature/syntax comparison matrix for SQL databases?

Tags: sql, database

I am looking for a reference guide with possibility one or more comparison matrices for various SQL databases. The goal being to be able to see quickly what functions/operators/statements of the SQL standards (yes, plural would be good :) are supported by each and what syntax they use for them.

And then something similar for additional features as well, possibly matching them with equivalent features in other databases.

For instance, I'd like to be able to quickly see if database A, B, C support the `LIKE` operator and if they all support both the `%` and `_` placeholders.

This [Wikipedia comparison of several RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems) mentioned in similar questions gives some interesting info but not to the extent of the syntactic features and operator support.

Preferably, I'm looking for a reference containing said info for at least the following tables:

- Oracle,
- PostgreSQL,
- DB2,
- HSQLDB,
- MS SQL,
- MySQL.

Haven't managed to find a good consolidated and usable reference for this over the past few days. Thanks.

Comment: after working with MSSQL for 10 years i will find this resource usefull.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found this reference very useful:

[Comparison of different SQL implementations](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/)

Comment: you were first:) That's an OK reference, but I already had it and it's not nearly exhaustive enough (for instance, date support is fairly limited, and the LIKE operator is not really discussed either).

Comment: LIKE and the standard wildcards are something that work the same way in all DBMS you listed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Might be so, I'm no SQL expert. But then I'd have been glad to find a reference stating that. And what doesn't work the same way for instance is the escaping of these statements (where Oracle and DB2 allow you to specify the escape character of a LIKE, for instance).

Comment: @Haylem: from my experience, the author of that page is open for suggestions. You might try to ask him to add the missing bits and pieces. Btw: here is another comparison between SQL Server, MySQL and PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/130-Cross-Compare-of-PostgreSQL-8.4,-SQL-Server-2008,-MySQL-5.1.html

Answer (score 2):

You might find this book very useful: [SQL in a Nutshell (by Kline & Hunt, O'Reilly)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596518846)

Comment: Hmmm, a book. How 20th century of you:) Actually, I think I saw it on the desk of the tester working on the component I'm developing and for which I need that reference right now. Might just borrow that from her to see if it has what I need. Thanks.

Comment: @haylem, I am 55 years old, I like books better than websites for this type of information. This may not have every database you need but it's a good start on a bunch of them.

Comment: only kidding, I'm a lot younger (it will come...) but I'm a book worm myself. I appreciate a good paper reference as well.